# Object as an array

Tags: java, arrays, constructor

I need to create class Dog and PurebredDog extending Dog. Problem is that Dog can be at once single object and array of objects (Dogs and PurebreedDogs :

```
 Dog pack[]={new Dog(76589,"As","black",18,
                    "Ann","Kowalsky"),
           new PurebreedDog(45321,"Labrador","Elf","black",25, 
                          "Angus","Mati","Barbara","Smith"),
           new Dog(102467,"Gamma","brown",89,
                    "Josh","Coke"),
            new PurebreedDog(9678,"York","Theta","brown",8,
                    "Emka","Figaro","Alice","Cat")};    

for(int i=0; i < pack.length; i++)
  System.out.println(pack[i]+"\n\n");
```

How to write proper constructor for `Dog` ?
You could do :

```
public Dog(String name, etc){
}
```

but how to write constructor for array of dogs ?

```
public Dog(Dog[]tab) ?
```

And then how to recall it's elements ? Is `pack[]` a 2d array ?

Comment: what is the current problem?

Comment: I think he asks, how can he have a Constructor accepting indefinite args.

Comment: then let him ask it ;) furthermore, just today there was a question about variable method arguments.

Comment: @owca - sorry, it still doesn't make much more sense

Comment: It seems like a horrible idea to have a `Dog` class represent both a single dog and a collection of dogs.  Justin's suggestion to use a collection class for the latter is a good one.

Comment: sure thing, but this test code needs to work :/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To simplify things, an instance of `Dog` really should refer to a single Dog. So your constructor should look similar to (the data types are just examples):

```
Dog(int ID, String color, String name, ...)
```

`PurebreedDog` would subclass `Dog` and provide any additional constructor parameters (and members) such as `breed`, etc.

To deal with multiple dogs, I recommend you store instances of the class in a `List`, `HashTable`, or other type of data structure that is designed to hold multiple elements. The actual structure you use will depend upon your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

In your specific case, a `Dog` should represent *one* dog, and I agree with Justin's answer.

Just for the sake of completeness, I think it's worth mentioning the [**composite pattern**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern) though.

There are indeed some circumstances where an aggregation of objects can acts the same way as its individual parts. A traditional example is the folder/file hierarchy. Both responds to the same methods such as `size`, `delete`, etc.

That could even be used with you `Dog` example if you plan to model a genealogy tree. A dog is a dog, but can have *N* children.

Answer (score 1):

The way to make uniform the representation of one dog and many dogs is for each entity to be a list. The one-dog entity is simply a list with one dog in it; the multiple-dog entity, of course, has more than one dog in it.  But all you need to code is the (single) Dog, and then, as Justin and ewernli said, use a Collection - probably an ArrayList of Dog.

Trying to make the un-enlisted single Dog the "same" as a list of dogs is just crazy.

Comment: I know, but I'm not the one responsible for creating this task :/

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so did it the following way :

PurebreedDog class:

```
public class PurebreedDog extends Dog {

private String breed;
private String mother;
private String father;

public PurebreedDog(int id, String breed, String name, String color, int age,
        String owner_name, String owner_surname, String mother, String father){
    super(id, name, color, age, owner_name, owner_surname);
    this.breed = breed;
    this.mother = mother;
    this.father = father;
}

@Override
public String toString(){
    return super.toString()+"\n Pure breed dog \n"+"-------------------------------\n"+
            "BREED: "+this.breed+"\n"+"MOTHER: "+this.mother+"\n"+
            "FATHER: "+this.father+"\n-------------------------------";
}

}
```

Dog class:

```
public class Dog {

private int id;
private String name;
private String owner_name;
private String owner_surname;
private String color;
private int age;
private Dog[]pack;

public Dog(int i, String n, String c, int w, String on, String os){
    id = i;
    name = n;
    color = c;
    age = w;
    owner_name = on;
    owner_surname = os;
}

public Dog(Dog[]p){

    Dog[]group = new Dog[p.length];
    for(int i=0; i < p.length; i++){
        group[i] = p[i];
    }

    this.pack = group;

}

@Override
public String toString(){

    return "-------------------------------\n"+
            "idr: "+this.id+"\n"+"OWNER: "+this.owner_name+
            this.owner_surname+"\n"+"NAME: "+this.name+"\n"+
            "color: "+this.color+"\n-------------------------------";
}
```